# Perimeter of a right-angled triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I am a student of Class VII and studying for my examination. Can you please help me in solving this question?

Is the perimeter of a right-angled triangle of base $b$, hypotenuse $l$ and height $h$, $2(l+b+h)$?

Answer (score 1):

No. The perimeter of your triangle is the sum of the length of the sides:

$$l + b + h$$

In a right triangle, the base $b$ and height $h$ can be seen as the *legs* of the right-triangle with hypotenuse $l$.

Comment: uhm, yes. but $h$ is the height, not a side. And in a rectangular triangle, the base is the hypothenuse, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: In a right triangle, the height *is* the length of of the side forming the right-angle with the base. Remember, the height of a triangle is its *perpendicular distance* from the base to the opposite vertex. No, the base of a right-triangle is not its hypotenuse. The hypotenuse of a right-triangle does not form a right angle with either of the other sides.

Comment: @Thomas The base of a triangle is the side you choose to draw at the bottom, and this choice is completely arbitrary. Also, in this problem it is implied that the hypotenuse is not the base because while the base & height of triangle determines its area, it doesn't determine its perimeter (which is what's being asked for).